# use X509Certificate field in SAML assertion or an external cert file.

Tags: security, single-sign-on, x509certificate, saml, saml-2.0

As Identity Provider we send a SAML assertion request to Service Provider and then they validate our signature in assertion using our certificate. SAML assertion contains an optional field  called X509Certificate which is certificate of assertion issuer. (our certificate). My question is that from a security perspective is it better Service Provider use this field in each assertion for validating signature or use an external certificate file.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very bad idea for them to only trust the public key value that is included in a signed message. Who's to say that someone couldn't just forge your EntityID and send them random SAMLResponses with some user data? The signature of the message would be valid, and they are using the key included in the message to validate the signature, right?

The benefits of offline key exchange are well known: Your SP has securely stored your public key and will always use to it validate the signature of your messages unless you instruct them otherwise (key rollover/update). If you include your certificate in the message, the SP will compare the two certificates first to ensure they match and then they should use the copy they have stored previously (assuming they match). Otherwise the message is rejected.

However, if you want an SP to trust the public key you include in your messages, the SP *must*  be able to ensure that it is YOUR certificate that is being used. There are some smart folks at Ping Identity who have thought about this SP DSig Validation Use Case -- you can find a description of how they do this in their "Anchored Certificate" model for DSig Validation.

https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf80/index.shtml#concept_digitalSigningPolicyCoordination.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get the 11/19 answer.  If you send your BinarySecurityToken (BST) in the Assertion for signature validation, and the receiver has an entry in his trust store with this public certificate, you should be good.  In order for this to work:

1) The receiver must require that the assertion is signed

2) The receiver must check the signature verifying certificate in the assertion against a trust store.

3) DO NOT just trust the dn/issuer of the signer instead of using a trust store; that can be faked in a signing certificate.

If these things are followed, you have verified that the message is signed by the holder of the private key and that the assertion has not changed in flight.  You then trust that holder, therefore you can proceed.

If the receiver doesn't require that an assertion is signed, anyone can send anything to the receiver.
If the receiver doesn't check a trust store for the verifying certificate, anyone can send a signed anything to the receiver.

The advantage of sending the BST in the message is that when your IdP certificate expires and you have to get a new one, the client only has to add your new certificate to his trust store instead of changing the configuration of his application.